# How to turn Flex MXML DataGrid into something like Horisontal DataGrid? (see an Image)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, datagrid, mxml

**from this (normal dataGrid)**

[image: normal data grid]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/mxDataGrid.jpg))</sub>

**into this (horisontal data grid)**

[image: horisontal data grid]

How to turn Flex MXML DataGrid into something like Horisontal DataGrid? (may be some how with Flash builder 4?)

Keeping all stuff DataGrid has like eating data from data provider sortind dragging - droping items etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. I have tried to do this myself. 
My suggestion is to use DataGrid:
Turn off headers,
and make the first column of your datagrid use itemRenderers, where the itemRenderer for the first column renders the same gradient rendering as the headers (you can look at the DataGridHeaderBackgroundSkin.as class to see what kind of rendering code you need).

I'm not sure how to do the highlighting per column though.

Thanks, let me know if this helps!